# Higher level Method to Encrypt with a given Session Key (Session Key is Encrypted with Public Key)

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, aes, rsa

I'm using **openssl**（**RSA**+**AES**) to do the encryption between client and server, here is my scenario:

I Client:

1. randomly generate a aes key as session key
2. use session key to encrypt the request
3. use server's rsa public key to encrypt session key
4. send encrypted request and encrypted session key to server

II Server:

1. decrypt session key with it's rsa private key
2. decrypt request with session key
3. encrypt response with **the same session key**
4. send encrypted response back to client

III Client:

1. decrypt response with **the same session key**

---

I'm writing the server side code with **c++** and here are my problems:

1. Is it right that I use the same session key for the response? Or should I generate the RSA public key and private key for client too? So that the response can also be encrypted by a random session key generated by the server side, and then use client's public key to encrypt the session key.
2. If the senario above could work: I know that to get the decrypted request, I can use openssl's high level `EVP Open` function with the encrypted session key and the private key.
   But is there a similar high level function to encrypt the response **with the specified encrypted session key and server's private key** by **one step** too? Or I should write the code with openssl's `RSA_decrypt` and `AES_encrypt` by hand (but 2 steps)?

Comment: why not using SSL functions of openssl ? If you don't know what you doing chance may very high that you write an insecure application.You can implement your server-side part using a standard HTTP Server like Apache with HTTPS and maybe JSON to exchange data with the your C ssl client. That's good to implement and you may not risk too much into failures implementing encryption and key-exchange. Please think about it.

Comment: @lkj I acually have thought about this. But latency is a very important measure in our service, and https will take much more time on extra procedures. So I prefer use http.

Comment: well, I have enough experience to know that this kind of toughs are the base to walks right into some security-nightmares :-) And I have done enough with openssl & encryption. You have been warned my friend ! :-)

Comment: If you care about latency that much, you probably wouldn't be using HTTP either. On the other hand, TLS supports mechanisms (such as session resumption) that will be far faster than even your proposed cut-down mechanism, whilst still remaining secure. Your roll-your-own protocol also fails on the security front, e.g. it doesn't have perfect forward secrecy. In summary **Use HTTPS**!